# IUPAC names accidentally differing in hyphen only

Tags: nomenclature

Here is an example of two compounds

> $$\ce{CH3CH2COOCH3}$$
>   *vs*
>   $$\ce{(CH3)2CHCOO-}$$

i.e.

> [image]
>   *vs*
>   [image]

whose possible IUPAC names

> methyl propanoate
>   *vs*
>   methylpropanoate

accidentally differ only in presence/absence of a space. (Note that complete, unambiguous name of the second compound is 2-methylpropanoate)

Is there an (accidental) example of two IUPAC names for different compounds, that differ only in presence/absence of a **hyphen** ("-") instead?

(Question might sound hypothetical, strange and inappropriate, but is related to to [this one](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/74049/hyphenation-of-chemical-names))

**UPDATE**: Mentioned ‘methylpropanoate’ preferred IUPAC name is 2-methylpropanoate. There's a better example pair:

- phenyl acetate ($\ce{CH3COOPh}$)
- phenylacetate ($\ce{PhCH2COO^{-}}$)

Note that in some language localized official IUPAC nomenclatures, the names really differ by the hyphen instead of the space (e.g. in Czech: fenyl-acetát vs fenylacetát), but I was wondering about the English nomenclature.

Answer (score 2):

The compound with the formula $\ce{CH3COOPh}$ is known as phenyl acetate, but the IUPAC name is: phenyl ethanoate.

The compound $\ce{PhCH2COO-}$ has the IUPAC name: 2-phenylethanoate.

The similarity is interesting, but the names are distinct enough, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Note that a IUPAC name is not a synonym for a systematic name . **preferred** IUPAC names are acetic acid/acetate, while ethanoic acid/ethanoate are **systematic** IUPAC names.

Comment: What you say is almost 10 years old info, look at IUPAC 2013 Organic chemistry nomenclature (Blue book).